# WPF: how to add image/icon to my Menu with condition

Tags: wpf, menu, menuitem

This is my `Style`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Menu}" x:Key="StandardMenu">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}" TargetType="Separator">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Separator">
                            <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource MenuSeparatorBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" Margin="25,0,0,0"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Menu}}}"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource ApplicationFontSize}"/>
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                            <!--Border 1-->
                            <Border x:Name="Border" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent"  CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                                <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col0" MinWidth="17" Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuTextColumnGroup"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col3" Width="14"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" x:Name="Icon" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Icon"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" x:Name="HeaderHost" RecognizesAccessKey="True" ContentSource="Header" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2" Margin="8,1,8,1" x:Name="IGTHost" ContentSource="InputGestureText" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <Grid Grid.Column="3" Margin="4,0,6,0" x:Name="ArrowPanel" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                        <Path x:Name="ArrowPanelPath" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Data="M0,0 L0,8 L4,4 z"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Popup IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                           Placement="Right"
                                           HorizontalOffset="-1" 
                                           x:Name="SubMenuPopup"
                                           Focusable="false"
                                           PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}"
                                           AllowsTransparency="True">
                                        <Grid Margin="0,0,5,5">
                                            <!--Border 2-->
                                            <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" CornerRadius="5"
                                                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource MenuSeparatorBorderBrush}"
                                                    BorderThickness="1" 
                                                    Background="{StaticResource SubmenuItemBackground}" 
                                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                                <Grid x:Name="SubMenu" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" Margin="2">
                                                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                                <Border.Effect>
                                                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="2" Color="Black"/>
                                                </Border.Effect>
                                            </Border>
                                            <!--Border 3-->
                                            <Border Margin="1,0,0,0"
                                                    x:Name="TransitionBorder"
                                                    Width="0" 
                                                    Height="2" 
                                                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                                    Background="{StaticResource SubmenuItemBackground}"
                                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="False"
                                                    BorderThickness="1" 
                                                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource SubmenuItemBackground}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Popup>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="true">
                                    // Here i want to see my icon/image
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LightBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Foreground}"/>
    </Style>
```

My `View model` has this `Property` called `IsSelected` and when this `bool` value is true i want to see my image from my `Resources` folder.

So i know my trigger should be something like that or similar:

```
 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="true">
       // Here i want to see my icon/image
 </DataTrigger>
```

But where i need to add this image insode my `Style` ?

**update**

This is my `Menu`:

```
<Menu Name="menuInterfaces" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" Margin="0,8,0,0" Style="{StaticResource StandardMenu}">
                                <Menu.ItemTemplate>
                                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Menu:MenuItemViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems}">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Width}"/>

                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Width}"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/checked_lightslategray.ico"
                                               Width="12"
                                               Height="12"
                                               Grid.Column="0"
                                               Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                            <Image.Style>
                                                <Style TargetType="Image">
                                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Value="False">
                                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                                </Style>
                                            </Image.Style>
                                        </Image>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"
                                                   Grid.Column="2"
                                                   Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                            </Menu.ItemTemplate>
                        </Menu>
```

Result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dW6wZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified where the image is supposed to go so I'll assume it's meant to go in the left-most column of your grid. You achieve this by styling the image and adding your DataTrigger to that instead:

```
<Style x:Key="MenuImageStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
    <Setter  Property="Source" Value="check.png" />     <!--Image filename-->
    <Setter  Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />    <!--Default value-->
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="true">
            <Setter  Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And then you just add the image to your grid elements:

```
<Image Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource MenuImageStyle}" />
```

Comment: Where i need to put this Imahe Stye ? unside my StandardMenu Style ? BTW i want this Image locate on the left side where the Icon should be

Comment: Please see my update image, i want the image will locate on the left side where the  Icon should be otherwise it looks bad like what happening to my now

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite understanding what you're saying. Ordinarily you would set MenuItem.Icon, but since you're templating the MenuItem you need to explicitly add the image to Column 0 of your grid. The code I posted should do that. If you don't want the empty space to the left when none of your menu items are checked then used "Collapsed" instead of "Hidden".

Comment: But where i need to add this Image with this MenuImageStyle ? inside my Menu ? can i have please shot code example ? i added my menu code

Comment: Where is this Grid that you mention ?

Comment: Your updated code works fine, just take out the '<ControlTemplate.Triggers>' block.

Comment: The `<Grid>` inside your HierarchicalDataTemplate. You added the image there yourself in your update.

Comment: According my code this is almost what i have done, my question is how to put this image on the left MenuItem side where the icon should be place